# Laravel 5.4 - Send array from form to controller by using ul and li's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a model **Testcase** in my database which has a field called "testcaseOrder" which I use to order my models in the view.
I render all **Testcase** models into a form and implemented some logic, so I can rearrange the order by using drag & drop and then update the models with the new order.

```
<form id="store" class="center" method="POST" action="{{url("testcase/updateOrder/$model_id")}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable form-group">
      @foreach($AllTestcases as $testcase)
          <li class="ui-state-default" name="testcases[]" id="{{ $testcase->id }}" value="{{ $testcase->testcaseOrder }}">{{ $testcase->name }}</li>
      @endforeach
  </ul>

  <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default">Speichern</button>
  </div>

  @include('partials.errors')

</form>
```

After submitting the form I try to access the values in my controller like  this:

```
public function updateOrder($scenario_id)
{
    dd(request('testcases'));
    ...
}
```

However, I get `null` back as result.
What am I doing wrong?

---

**Notes**:

I already checked if `$model_id` and `$scenario_id` are correct.

`$testcase->testcaseOrder` is of type integer

Comment: Did you try looking at `print_r($_POST)` output?

Comment: This outputs: `Array ( [_token] => GaHijGxlKRvwE5qUUORiWZLsfAB0plnDB72dmcFu ) `

Comment: Then your form doesn't work as expected. Are you using an ajax call for submitting?

Comment: @TahaPaksu, no I just submit it normal like you can see in my code above.

Comment: Wow, sorry I just realised that <li> elements are not form inputs. you should try using one.

Comment: ul and li are not part the form.. use select and option tag

Comment: @BilalAhmed, The drag & drop will not work with select and option

Comment: then on submit call jquery to get data and submit form using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your list to this:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <input type="hidden" name="testcases[]" id="{{ $testcase->id }}" value="{{ $testcase->testcaseOrder }}" />
    {{ $testcase->name }}
</li>
```

Comment: or maybe you would want to move the id to the <li>. If you're using it like that.